# Spring Boot JDBC Exception Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ojdbc

I am trying to learn Spring Boot. I am doing it via a tutorial on the Spring website. I created a project in eclipse. And I added the JDBC dependency in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
    <version>10.2.0.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I downloaded the ojdbc14 jar from Oracle and ran the command:

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.0.5.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc14.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

My application.properties is done like:

```
#Oracle connection
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@URL:1521:SID
spring.datasource.data-username=XXXX
spring.datasource.data-password=XXXX
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.org.springframework.retry=DEBUG
management.security.enabled=false
```

When I try to start the application, I see the exception:

```
2018-03-14 18:02:01.013 ERROR 5844 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.

org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:305) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.cleanUpExpiredSessions(JdbcOperationsSessionRepository.java:525) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration.lambda$configureTasks$0(JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration.java:194) ~[spring-session-jdbc-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) [spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:147) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:209) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:236) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:454) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:802) ~[ojdbc14-10.2.0.5.0.jar:Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.5.0"]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:262) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running on Java 8 which requires `ojdbc7.jar` or `ojdbc8.jar` if you are on 12c or possibly `ojdbc6.jar` if you are still on 11g. See 
[What are the Oracle JDBC releases versus JDK versions?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03_1) for the whole compatibility list.

Don't use `ojdbc14.jar` which was released ages ago for way older JVMs.

Also `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` is redundant. Spring Boot should figure it out based on JDBC URL.

Comment: Ah..... thanks! I will give that a try and post back. I probably got put off by the higher number I guess! :)